# How do i disable italics on javascript comments in VSCode

Tags: comments, visual-studio-code

I would love to format my js comment to remove the italics and maybe change its font as well.

[image]

I would love it to look more like the laravel comment below.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the font-style of code comments in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75041538/how-to-change-the-font-style-of-code-comments-in-vscode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [customize your theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) in VS code. For this specific case, add the following lines to your configuration:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": [
                    "comment.block.js",
                    "comment.line.double-slash.js",
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "",
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Maybe there are more scopes to cover. If some comments still appear in italic, run the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command while the cursor is on the comment and add the displayed scope to the `scope` list.

However, if you'd like to change the comment style for all languages, you can use this general setting:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": {
            "fontStyle": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Changing the font itself for specific tokens it not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not help me. Also the value None for fontstyle throws an error saying ``` expecting value jsonc ```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I updated the answer. It should work with `"fontStyle": ""`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my question either. I still have the comments in italics, am using a theme called slime though, could it be the one affecting the styles? Thanks @carlfriedrich.

Comment: In your screenshot you only have block comments. Maybe you are using a different style of comments now? My previous reply only changed the block comment style. I extended the answer again with another comment style and information on how to find out more styles, as well as a general configuration to change ALL comment styles at once. Does that help?

Comment: DId that finally help?