# How to change the font-style of code comments in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want italic.How to change it?

I want a regular font style instead of italic.
[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the setting.json：

```js
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": {
      "fontStyle": "",
      "foreground": "#d400ff"
    }
  }
```

[image]
You can change the font style and color.